# why i still receive the Jenkins Email?

Tags: jenkins

i used have several Jenkins in the Linux,but i use kill -9 pid kill them all,and only one in the Linux,that shows my Jenkins build just 719,the email shows the build is already 748,i do not know why i still receive email,can anyone tell me why? thanks a lot 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIf2w.png)

Comment: Is the question regarding the build url or regarding with the emails?

Comment: the email, i shut down the build several days ago,but i receive the email everyday,when i jump to the build URL in the email, it found 404! in that case,i am not able to stop those email which send me everyday~